# Why does does SSE set (_mm_set_ps) reverse the order of arguments

Tags: c++, c, simd, sse, intrinsics

I recently noticed that

```
_m128 m = _mm_set_ps(0,1,2,3);
```

puts the 4 floats into reverse order when cast to a float array:

```
(float*) p = (float*)(&m);
// p[0] == 3
// p[1] == 2
// p[2] == 1
// p[3] == 0
```

The same happens with a `union { _m128 m; float[4] a; }` also.

Why do SSE operations use this ordering? It's not a big deal but slightly confusing.

**And a follow-up question:**

When accessing elements in the array by index, should one access in the order `0..3` or the order `3..0` ?

Comment: Related: [Convention for displaying vector registers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41351087).  The only thing that's "reversed" is the arg order of `_mm_set` intrinsics; everything else is normal little-endian; don't access your elements backwards unless that's easier for some other reason.  Also, aliasing a `float*` onto a `__m128` is not well-defined behaviour across compilers (strict-aliasing violation); see [print a \_\_m128i variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46752535)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a convention; they had to pick *some* order, and it really doesn't matter what the order is as long as everyone follows it.  Intel happens to like little-endianness.

As far as accessing by index goes... the best thing is to try to avoid doing it.  Nothing kills vector performance like element-wise accesses.  If you must, try set things up so that the indexing matches the hardware vector lanes; that's what most vector programmers (in my experience) will expect.

Comment: Intel doesn’t follow their own order. You can test with e.g. _mm_extract_ps() intrinsic that accepts integer index.

Answer (score 8):

Depend on what you would like to do, you can use either `_mm_set_ps` or `_mm_setr_ps`.

> ```
> __m128 _mm_setr_ps (float z, float y, float x, float w )
> ```
>
> Sets the four SP FP values to the four inputs in reverse order.

Answer (score 7):

Isn't that consistent with the little-endian nature of x86 hardware? The way it stores the bytes of a long long.

Comment: Yes, it's just normal little endian ordering. For SSE (and SIMD programming in general) the actual order of the elements doesn't matter too much in general, *except* for when you start changing the width of elements (packing/unpacking, etc) or doing anything which accesses specific elements (permutations, insert/extract, etc).