# How to cast integer array to SIMD vector

Tags: c++, casting, simd, icc

I try to represent a `__int16` array as a `__m128i` element.
Casting `__m128i` element to `__int16` array works nicely.
My example code:

```
void example() {
   __m128i v = _mm_set_epi16(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
   __int16 *p_i = (__int16 *)&v; 
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
       std::cout <<p_i[i] << " "; // 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
   std::cout << "\n";

   __int16 i2[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
   __m128i *p_v2 = (__m128i *) i2;
   std::cout << __m128i_toString<__int16>(p_v2[0])<< "\n"; //error here
}
```

`__m128i_toString<>()` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26012188)

What did I miss?

Comment: What error do you get ? It works fine for me (after I change `__int16` to `int16_t` and add the necessary `#include`s).

Comment: It's runtime error. "unhandled exception at '0x000488d9' in IntelHi.exe: 0xC000005: access violation when reading '0xfffffff'"

Comment: Oh - probably just alignment then - try aligning your data - add `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` to your `__int16` array declaration.

Comment: look's like Intel compiler doesn't support `__attribute__` I will try find some equivalent

Comment: `__declspec(align(16))` looks same. I added it before `__int16` array data and it works. Thanks a lot. But i can't understand what i am doing now.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx

Comment: I think the Intel compiler supports `__attribute__` on Linux, but maybe you're using the Windows version ? `__declspec(align(16))` serves much the same purpose, but it's mainly a Windows thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107079/discussion-between-stepan-loginov-and-paul-r).

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, you can use `alignas(16) int16_t i2[8] = ...` to get 16B-alignment in a *portable* way without any compiler-specific extensions like `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` or `__declspec(align(16))`.

See [the code on godbolt compiled with `alignas`](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22intel%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QFt3gC4CdwB0AFgHwBQoksiqIA9gM54ICG65l08yKTcOxcmWwBPAA4JEAMyQ4AjADYA%2BtiRKl8hQG4yZAG50QcJGPxhsS9HIBMADhAAKdVbsgAlDv2HjCAB5sxKAQHNyQAbzIkKOcbeyQ9JABeNUwlBgQLBDEQRQc5ABoka0KAZkKAFkKAVkKFQoB2QtsPSOiNc0UkACoxDSSkJ3bsTq63ADI9LSRWpCk6XAGcWX6ABimQVCRbdYBqHbcZqKi%2BAC4TiDoYVRQUXpAAbRAAXVQUJAAiD6mAem%2BtpHqSAUSCqSHKSBKRSQchmp3Ol2ub3eAB0wO9PEcWFAQABzMAsBh5BShdSaWTWe62F7JMIFIqlCrVWoNJoAXx0Rxirm6vT01n6gxccVG5I5SF%2BSBgYGk4EksylEGw9DAUV%2BcIuV1eakssRAKjoAGU8OAcShSR0FCQHLyKSsnm4bh9Uejxd8ELhcPMkER3QhWqYcDrXA4eko%2BS1WWQgA%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22clang371%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O3%20-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%20-fverbose-asm%20-ffast-math%20-march%3Dhaswell%20-mno-avx%22%7D%5D%7D).

Note that you should generally avoid aliasing `__m128i` with short integer arrays of the same length.  Getting data into vectors that way causes stalls from failed store-forwarding.  Doing horizontal operations by storing to an array and then processing with scalar code also [sucks compared to SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026/224132).

Using `_mm_set_epi16()` will probably lead to better code, because the compiler doesn't have to optimize away the actual array and pointer operations.  In this case, it was able to (clang just does a `movaps` from a read-only constant, with no storing to an array first).  If the initializer wasn't a compile-time constant, you might not get such good results.