# Using a variable to index a simd vector with _mm256_extract_epi32() intrinsic

Tags: simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I am using the AVX intrinsic [_mm256_extract_epi32()](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX,AVX2&text=extract&expand=2287).

I am not entirely sure if I am using it correctly, though, because gcc doesn't like my code, whereas clang compiles it and runs it without issue.

I am extracting the lane based on the value of an integer variable, as opposed to using a constant.

When compiling the following snippet with clang3.8 (or clang4) for avx2, it [generates code](https://godbolt.org/g/d2zkab) and uses the [vpermd](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/VPERMD_VPERMW.html) instruction.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t foo( int a, __m256i vec )
{
    uint32_t e = _mm256_extract_epi32( vec, a );
    return e*e;
}
```

Now, if I use gcc instead, let's say gcc 7.2 then the compiler fails to generate code, with the errors:

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/include/immintrin.h:41:0,
                 from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/include/avxintrin.h: In function 'foo':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/include/avxintrin.h:524:20: error: the last argument must be a 1-bit immediate
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_vextractf128_si256 ((__v8si)__X, __N);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/include/immintrin.h:37:0,
                 from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/include/smmintrin.h:449:11: error: selector must be an integer constant in the range 0..3
    return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v4si ((__v4si)__X, __N);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have two issues with this:

1. Why is clang fine with using a variable, and does gcc want a
   constant?
2. Why can't gcc make up its mind? First it demands a **1-bit immediate value**, and later it wants an **integer constant in the range 0..3** and those are different things.

Intels Intrinsics Guide doesn't specify constraints on the index value for _mm256_extract_epi32() by the way, so who's right here, gcc or clang?

Comment: Note: clang5 also compiles the code, but makes a round trip to memory to extract the lane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently GCC and Clang made a different choice.
IMHO GCC has made the right choice by not implementing this for variable indices. Intrinsic `_mm256_extract_epi32` doesn't translate to a single instruction. With a variable index this intrinsic might lead to inefficient code,
if it is used in a performance critical loop.

For example, Clang 3.8 needs 4 instructions to implement `_mm256_extract_epi32` with a variable index.
GCC forces the programmer to think about more efficient code that avoids `_mm256_extract_epi32` with variable indices.

Nevertheless, sometimes it is useful to have a portable (gcc, clang, icc) function, which emulates `_mm256_extract_epi32`
with variable a index:

```c
uint32_t mm256_extract_epi32_var_indx(const __m256i vec, const unsigned int i) {   
    __m128i indx = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(i);
    __m256i val  = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(vec, _mm256_castsi128_si256(indx));
    return         _mm_cvtsi128_si32(_mm256_castsi256_si128(val));
}
```

This should compile to three instructions after inlining: two `vmovd`s and a `vpermd` (gcc 8.2 with `-m64 -march=skylake -O3`):

```
mm256_extract_epi32_var_indx:
  vmovd xmm1, edi
  vpermd ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
  vmovd eax, xmm0
  vzeroupper
  ret
```

Note that the intrinsics guide describes that the result is 0 for indices
>=8 (which is an unusual case anyway). With Clang 3.8, and with `mm256_extract_epi32_var_indx`, the index is reduced modulo 8. In other words: only the 3 least significant bits of the index are used.
Note that Clang 5.0's round trip to memory isn't very efficient too,
see [this Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/my4oUN). Clang 7.0
fails to compile `_mm256_extract_epi32` with variable indices.

As [@Peter Cordes commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726032/using-a-variable-to-index-a-simd-vector-with-mm256-extract-epi32-intrinsic#comment84452422_48726371): with a fixed index 0, 1, 2, or 3, only a single `pextrd` instruction is needed to
extract the integer from the xmm register. With a fixed index 4, 5, 6, or 7, two instructions are required.
Unfortunately, a `vpextrd` instruction working on 256-bit ymm registers doesn't exist.

---

The next example illustrates my answer:

A naive programmer starting with SIMD intrinsics might write
the following code to sum the elements 0, 1, ..., j-1, with `j<8`, from `vec`.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t foo( __m256i vec , int j)
{   
    uint32_t sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){
        sum = sum + (uint32_t)_mm256_extract_epi32( vec, i );
    }
    return sum;
}
```

With Clang 3.8 this compiles to about 50 [instructions](https://godbolt.org/g/j8wsyL) with branches and loops. GCC fails to compile this code.
Obviously an efficient code to sum these elements is likely based on:

1. mask out the elements j, j+1, ..., 7, and
2. compute the horizontal sum.

Comment: It would be nice if there was more portable syntax for indexing vector elements, for debug-print functions.  `_mm256_extract_epi32` seems like a reasonable place to put that overload, if compilers agreed with each other, because [the `vpextrd`  machine instruction](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/PEXTRB_PEXTRD_PEXTRQ) is only available with XMM operands anyway, not 256 bit YMM.  `_mm256_extract_epi32` can't be a single instruction for indices >= 4.

Comment: Thanks, but not quite following you: if we ignore the >=8 index issue, surely an AND with 0x7, followed by VPERMD is pretty efficient (like clang outputs) ? I tried adding assert(a<8) to hint the compiler to leave out the AND, but it didn't. (btw, in my code, index is always less than 8)

Comment: In the old off-line intrinsics guide there was a warning displayed for the composite intrinsics: _Note: This intrinsic creates a sequence of two or more instructions, and may perform worse than a native instruction. Consider the performance impact of this intrinsic._ . I think the same warning applies here. Of course, the performance impact is negligible if this intrinsic isn't used too much. On Skylake the latency of the 2 `vmovd`-s and the `vpermd` is 7 cycles

Answer (score 6):

The `__N` it says must be a 1-bit immediate is *not* the 2nd arg to `_mm256_extract_epi32`, it's some function of that used as an arg to `__builtin_ia32_vextractf128_si256` (presumably the 3rd bit).  Then later it wants an integer constant in the 0..3 range for `vpextrd`, giving you a total of 3 bits of index.

`_mm256_extract_epi32` is a composite intrinsic, not directly defined in terms of a single `builtin` function.

`vpextrd r32, ymm, imm8` doesn't exist, only the xmm version exists, so `_mm256_extract_epi32` is a wrapper around `vextracti/f128` / `vpextrd`.  Gcc chooses to only make it work for compile-time constants so it always compiles to at most 2 instructions.

If you want runtime-variable vector indexing, you need to use different syntax; e.g. store to an array and load a scalar, and hope gcc optimizes that into a shuffle / extract.

Or define a GNU C native vector type with the right element width, and use `foo[i]` to index it like an array.

```
typedef int v8si __attribute__ ((vector_size (32)));
v8si tmp = foo;   // may need a cast to convert from __m256i
int element_i = tmp[i];
```

`__m256i` in gcc/clang is defined as a vector of `long long` elements, so if you index it directly with `[]`, you'll get qword elements.  (And your code won't compile with MSVC, which doesn't define `__m256i` that way at all.)

---

I haven't checked the asm for any of these recently: if you care about efficiency, you might want to manually design a shuffle using your runtime-variable index, like @Wim's answer suggests that clang does.

Comment: Related: [print a \_\_m128i variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13257166) shows the store/reload method with a temp array for portable runtime-variable indexing.  Compilers may optimize it into a shuffle anyway, like perhaps `vmovd xmm0, edi` / `vpermd ymm2, ymm1, ymm0`  / `vmovd eax,xmm2` to extract `ymm1[edi]` with 32-bit elements.  Or not, in which case store-forwarding is not bad for latency, and cheap.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you had compilation trouble with GCC, is that it made a rather, umm, unusual decision when implementing AVX.

in GCC, there is a built in vector type used to implement the simd types like __m256, __m128i, etc, instead of using a union like in MSVC. This is usually not too big of a deal for compatibility.

But for some reason, when going to 256 bits, gcc implemented __m256i as 4 64-bit ints, unlike __m128i which is 4 32 bit ints. For floats, GCC did the right thing and made __256 be 8 32-bit floats. Portable AVX SIMD wrappers that work with GCC+MSVC will have a fair amount of casting and hackery in the integer ops because of this :-(

Comment: GCC's current definition for `__m128i` is 2x 64-bit, `typedef long long __m128i __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));` in `emmintrin.h`, and hasn't changed for years.  Did some much older version of GCC implement `__m128i` as a vector of `int` or `int32_t`?  Or `long` on 32-bit systems?  https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/30fb3231107d372c2e9df88e18714baae783870e/gcc/config/i386/emmintrin.h from 2003 shows `__m128i` defined as `__v2di` (vector of two double-width integers, i.e. 2x 64-bit since single width `int` is 32-bit on x86.)  That's the oldest in that repo.

Comment: If you need to access single elements of a vector, the portable way is to store to a tmp array, as shown in my answers.  Some compilers will optimize that to a shuffle.  A runtime-variable index is inherently hard to deal with, given the limited choices of shuffles that exist.

Comment: Hmm you are right, my code is also full of casts for m128i also.
The big issue is that msvc, _and_ the intel docs don't do it as 64 bit elements.
Plus 32 bit ones are infinitely more common (at least in my game code).

Comment: The Intel intrinsics docs don't document any operator to index a `__m128i` directly, only intrinsic functions.  The internal definition is opaque as far as the portably-documented intrinsic API is concerned.