# What conversion is the SIMD packed fp32 to packed int32 doing?

Tags: c++, x86-64, simd

I am trying to convert fp32 values to int32 values with x86 SIMD instructions. Unfortunately, the result is not what I expect. Consider the following program (available on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Gjr4YddjT)):

```cpp
#include "immintrin.h"
#include "smmintrin.h" 
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    __m256 inp = {151.175064, 215.287735, 218.776123, 216.049164, 159.008453, 98.0167694, 75.8706512, 14.4608536};
    auto converted = _mm256_cvtps_epi32(inp);
    std::cout << " The converted results are: " <<
        (int)converted[0] << ", " <<
        (int)converted[1] << ", " <<
        (int)converted[2] << ", " <<
        (int)converted[3] << ", " <<
        (int)converted[4] << ", " <<
        (int)converted[5] << ", " <<
        (int)converted[6] << ", " <<
        (int)converted[7] << std::endl;
        
}
```

The code prints:  `The converted results are: 151, 219, 159, 76, 8236, 8236, 8236, 8236`. I expected the result to be `151, 215, 218, 216, 159, 98, 75, 14` (with floor truncation). The manual says about the [_mm256_cvtps_epi32](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm256_cvtps_epi32&ig_expand=2069) instruction:

> Convert packed single-precision (32-bit) floating-point elements in [...] to packed 32-bit integers

What do I need to do to cast fp32 floats to int32 and obtain the result I expect? Why are the printed results so funny?

Comment: I haven't checked, but are you sure that applying `operator[]` to a `__m256i` does what you think it does?

Comment: It's the current rounding mode, the default being the IEEE default of nearest, with even as a tie-break.  So it's like `lrint(x)` or `(int)nearbyint(x)`.  To match C casts, use `_mm256_cvttps_epi32` (note the extra `t`) for truncation toward 0 (not floor, that's toward -Inf so it's different for negative numbers).

Comment: But also, as Nate noticed, you're indexing wrong. In GNU C, `__m256i` is a vector of `long long` elements.  Casting them to `(int)` discards the high half so you don't have huge numbers, but you're indexing off the end.  Compile with warnings!  Wait, clang doesn't warn for this?  That's a nasty compiler bug, it should definitely warn you about this obvious (to the compiler which has the type information) UB.  GCC warns as expected, although only with `-Wall` enabled.  https://godbolt.org/z/rq6KPsvdz

Comment: You are looking for `_mm256_extract_epi32` - `converted[5]` and higher had silently overflown the mapped array.

Comment: Thanks for all the great comments! If I may (slightly off-topic), I often do a reduction over the simd register (array). Such a `float sum{0}; for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {sum += inp[i];}` when `inp` is a `__m256`.  So far, it worked, but that's UB then as well?

Comment: GCC defines `__m256` as a GNU C native vector of 8 floats, so indexing with indexes from 0 to 7 is well-defined.  Unlike with a `__m256i` which GCC defines as 4x `long long`.  But don't use loops like that to horizontal sum, especially without `-ffast-math` which would forbid the compiler from making efficient asm.  [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996764)

Comment: No, `__m256` is defined as an array of `fp32`. `__m256d` is defined as an array of `fp64`. Just `__m256i` is loosely defined as "some way 265 bit can be split into integer types".

Comment: [Using a variable to index a simd vector with \_mm256\_extract\_epi32() intrinsic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48726032) mentions a bit about how `[]` works on `__m256` / `__m256i`  the way GCC define them (which is *not* portable to compilers other than GCC/Clang, and maybe ICX)  Added that to the duplicate list.