# Difference between _mm_storeu_si128 and _mm_loadu_si128

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics

I was just wondering what were the differences between the two of these two intrinsic functions. The Intel Intrinsic Guide doesn't help much:

- `_mm_storeu_si128`: Store 128-bits of integer data from a into memory. `mem_addr` does not need to be aligned on any particular boundary.
- `_mm_loadu_si128`: Load 128-bits of integer data from memory into dst. `mem_addr` does not need to be aligned on any particular boundary.

All the difference is on the word `store` or `load` but the difference is not clear to me.

Comment: `Store` is used to move data from a register to a memory. So here, you move 128bits from a register to memory. `Load` is the opposite, you move 128bits from memory to your register.

Comment: A register is a variable like __m128i / __m64 / __m512 /... and memory is unsigned char, unsigned int etc ? So if I want to fill a __m128i structure with my 16 unsigned chars, I&#39;ll use _mm_loadu_si128 and the opposite is _mm_storeu_si128, it fills an unsigned char array with the _m128i structure. Am I right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C terms:

- load = read data pointed to by a pointer.
- store = write through a pointer.

For a simple type like `int`, aligned load and store functions could look like this:

```
int load(int *p) { return *p; }

void store(int *p, int val) { *p = val; }
```

(You'd actually use `memcpy` to get [unaligned and strict-aliasing-safe loads and stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510783/why-does-unaligned-access-to-mmaped-memory-sometimes-segfault-on-amd64).)

`__m128i` load/store functions mostly exist to communicate aligned vs. unaligned to the compiler, vs. dereferencing `__m128i*` directly.  And for `float` / `double`, they also avoid casts because `_mm_loadu_ps` takes a `const float*` arg.

Later Intel intrinsics take `void*` args, avoiding the need for a `_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)&my_struct)` or whatever, but unfortunately they didn't make that improvement until AVX-512 intrinsics.

---

In asm terms, a load reads data from memory into a register (or as a source operand for an ALU instruction).  A store writes data to memory.

C local variables are normally kept in registers, but of course your compiler is free to optimize intrinsic loads/stores the same way it can optimize dereferences of an `int *`.  e.g. it might optimize away a store/reload so the asm wouldn't contain an instruction to do that.

The fact that there are load and store intrinsics does *not* mean that `__m128i` "is a register".  It's like `int`; if/when it can be kept in a register, the compiler will do so, but you can make an array of `__m128i` or whatever.  load/store intrinsics can be optimized away, or a load can be folded into a memory source operand for an ALU instruction like `vpaddb`.

---

Related:

- [print a __m128i variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257166/print-a-m128i-variable) - it's not safe to point an `int *` at a `__m128i` object; that's a strict-aliasing violation.  Only the other way around, with `__m128i*` pointing at other things, is safe.  (And deref with `*` instead of a `loadu` intrinsic is only safe if aligned.)
- [Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605/is-reinterpret-casting-between-hardware-simd-vector-pointer-and-the-correspond)