# left shift of 128 bit number using AVX2 instruction

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I am trying to do left rotation of a 128 bit number in AVX2. Since there is no direct method of doing this, I have tried using left shift and right shift to accomplish my task.

Here is a snippet of my code to do the same.

```
        l = 4;
        r = 4;
        targetrotate = _mm_set_epi64x (l, r);
        targetleftrotate = _mm_sllv_epi64 (target, targetrotate);
```

The above c ode snippet rotates target by 4 to the left.
When I tested the above code with a sample input, I could see the result is not rotated correctly.

Here is the sample input and output

```
          input: 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef   fe dc ba 98 76 54 32 10
obtained output: 10 30 52 74 96 b8 da fc   e0 cf ad 8b 69 47 25 03
```

But, the output I expect is

```
                 12 34 56 78 9a bc de f0   ed cb a9 87 65 43 21 00
```

I know that I am doing something wrong. I want to know whether my expected output is right and if so, I want to know what am I doing wrong here.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: `sllv_epi64` shifts *within 64-bit elements* only, not of full 128-bit numbers.  It's also a shift, not a rotate, shifting in zeros instead of shifting in the high bits that get shifted out.  AVX512 has rotates (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vprold:vprolvd:vprolq:vprolvq), otherwise you need to emulate with shift `left|right`.  But from your desired output, you don't actually want a rotate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an endian issue with how you're printing your input and output.

**The left-most bytes within each 64-bit half are the least-significant bytes in your actual output**, so `0xfe << 4` becomes `0xe0`, with the `f` shifting into a higher byte.

See [Convention for displaying vector registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351087/convention-for-displaying-vector-registers) for more discussion of that.

Your "expected" output matches what you'd get if you were printing values high element first (highest address when stored).  But that's not what you're doing; you're printing each byte separately in ascending memory order.  x86 is little-endian.  This conflicts with the numeral system we use in English, where we read Arabic numerals from left to right, highest place-value on the left, effectively human big-endian.  Fun fact: The Arabic language reads from right to left so for them, written numbers are "human little-endian".

(And across elements, higher elements are at higher addresses; printing high *elements* first makes whole-vector shifts like `_mm_bslli_si128` aka `pslldq` make sense in the way it shifts bytes left between elements.)

If you're using a debugger, you're probably printing within that.  If you're using debug-prints, see [print a __m128i variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257166/print-a-m128i-variable).

---

BTW, you can use `_mm_set1_epi64x(4)` to put the same value in both elements of a vector, instead of using separate `l` and `r` variables with the same value.

In `_mm_set` intrinsics, the high elements come *first*, matching the diagrams in Intel's asm manuals, and matching the semantic meaning of "left" shift moving bits/bytes to the left.  (e.g. see Intel's diagrams an element-numbering for [pshufd, `_mm_shuffle_epi32`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pshufd))

---

BTW, AVX512 has [`vprolvq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vprold:vprolvd:vprolq:vprolvq) rotates.  But yes, to emulate rotates you want a SIMD version of `(x << n) | x >> (64-n)`.  Note that x86 SIMD shifts *saturate* the shift count, unlike scalar shifts which *mask* the count.  So `x >> 64` will shift out all the bits.  If you want to support rotate counts above 63, you probably need to mask.

([Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c) but you're using intrinsics so you don't have to worry about C shift-count UB, just the actual known hardware behaviour.)

Comment: You are right. It's an endian issue.
I could modify the byte order and get the expected result.  

My machine doesn't have support for AVX512. So, I am using AVX2 to implement rotation through right and left shift and finally xor the result.  

Also, thank you for pointing out to _mm_set1_epi64x. It was very useful.

Comment: @krishnan: ah I see, when skimming your question I missed that you were using shifts to emulate rotates.  I just saw discussion of both in a question about shifting.  Updated my answer with some notes about that.